# Error message in shell but runs smoothly otherwise

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently I have a program that asks the user for their username and password and compares this to a database to check if they correspond. If they do, the user is accepted, if they aren't, they'll be asked again. However when this is run, the code outputs the error:

```
 ' AttributeError: 'Login' object has no attribute 'pack''
```

I'm trying to figure out why it prints an error to python shell when the program runs smoothly otherwise? The user can still input their username and password after the error has occurred and the database check works fine but the error prints in python shell.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import sqlite3

class Login:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title = ("Please login.")

        self.label_1 = Label(master, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(master, text="Password")
        self.entry_1 = Entry(master)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(master)

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(master, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clickked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
        self.pack()

def _login_btn_clickked(self):
    print(self.entry_1.get())
    print(self.entry_2.get())

    username = (self.entry_1.get())
    password = (self.entry_2.get())

    GetDatabase(username,password)
```

Comment: You need to show us, how you use the `Login` class.

Comment: The error is telling you the truth. The `Login` class has no attribute `pack`. Why do you think it does? The `Login` class is not a widget, so why are you trying to call `pack` on it?

Comment: What are you creating `self.master` a a class attribute when you are not even using it? `self.master` is not used anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
self.pack()
```

You are calling a method that doesn't exist.
EDIT:
In the code Login class was not specified to inherit from any class. In this case there are two possibilities.

Python2
When the base class is not specified the class will be almost empty except the custom methods and attributes we specify in the class([more](http://pythonu-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Classes.html)).

Python3

When the base class is not specified the class inherits from object class by default([more](http://pythonu-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Classes.html)).

Assuming you are using python 3 the only base class of Login class is object class. Therefore to call method self.pack() it should be either defined in base class(object class) or in Login class. But the method is not defined in either base class or Login class. To see the methods defined in object class you can use the following code from  [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html).

```
methodList = [method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]
print(methodList)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__','__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__','__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

But as it can be inferred from the code, you are trying to call pack method of the `master` object. You may need to change

```
self.pack()
```

to

```
self.master.pack()
```

Comment: I am not sure why your answer was down voted but it might be due to the lack of detail. Maybe explain what the class object type is and why that does not have `pack()` as a method. Just saying the method does not exist does not add any meaning full information to someone who already does not understand what their class object is.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to remove the line

```
self.pack()
```

at the end of the `__init__` method, or you have to inherit the `Login` class from a class which has the `pack()` method already defined.

Comment: No, tkinter does not execute the UI in an extra thread. If they are using IDLE or some other tool, that tool might run the entire program in another thread, but tkinter code runs in a single thread, which will be the main thread  unless it is explicitly put in another thread.

Comment: self.master.pack() doesn't work. It produces the error "AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'pack'". Removing the self.pack() however does work.

Comment: Even though the OP does not show what they are using for master it is very likely it is along the lines of `root = Tk()` and if that is the case then `self.master.pack()` will not work and probably should be removed from your answer as there is not enough information to be sure.

Comment: Updated my answer according to the feedback